# Jquery .click not not showing photos in any version of IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am having trouble with a a simple jquery script that is not working in any version of IE and hoping someone can help!  It works in all the other browsers.  The idea is when you click on each thumbnail - it calls up text and images from the js file.  Here is my html:

```
   <div id="project" class="box">
   <img src="" width="" height="" class="proj_img">
   </div>

   <div class="boundingBox" id="content">   
    <ul id="portfolio-list">        
        <li class="print">
        <a href="#project" class="callprint print1"></a>
        </li>
   </ul></div>
```

CSS:

```
.proj_img { 
max-width: 75%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
left: 25.416666666667%; /*adjust with media queries*/
border: 2px solid #d9d8d7;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
-moz-box-shadow:  0px 0px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
-o-box-shadow:  0px 0px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
box-shadow:  0px 0px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

And here is the portion of my js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#project').slideDown("slow");
    $('.print1').click(function(){
$('#proj_img').attr('src','img/print1.jpg');
    }); //click
    });
```

It used to work - but somewhere along the line it broke. I did update to this version of jquery to work with a plugin I installed:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Could it be something to do with the version of jquery?  Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.  Here's the link to my site if you want to view the whole source: http://meghankuntz.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the src with this:

```
$('#proj_img').attr('src','img/print1.jpg');
```

Your `slideDown()` function can also be reduced to:

```
$('#project').slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but it didn't work.  However I have that piece of code repeating 36 times in my js file, as there are 36 different images - would I have to change them all to the code you suggested for it to work?  I only tested on one.

Comment: Shouldn't have to. What's going on inside your slideDown function? That isn't normal?

Comment: Thanks but didn't work - I changed the src to the format you suggested for every post.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've updated the code above to reflect where I'm currently at thanks to your help.  Fixed up the slideDown function, and I made the img id into a class.  I also included where the code is firing, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @user2425955 you should not repeat code, you have machines for that. Use proper classes / data-attributes / ids instead of copy-pasting around.

Comment: @moonwave99 can you be more specific?  Which part of my code above isn't using proper classes, etc.?

Comment: @user2425955 if you are repeating the same snippet for many DOM elements, you could use a `data-image` attribute with the img url, then do just like `$([data-image]).click(function(){ $('#proj_img').attr('src', $(this).data('image')) })`. This way your code is maintainable, and ready for an arbitrary number of pics ^^.

Comment: @moonwave99 I agree - my code leaves a lot to be desired, js is not my strong suit!  However, It was working before, and in the other browsers, I don't have time to re-code the entire site - I feel like it's just something simple in calling the image that isn't working in IE.  Can you suggest anything else?  Thanks for your replies, I'm ready to bash my head into a wall.